# Does this mean I cannot do pre-market trading?

Tags: united-states, stocks, trading

I am a Fidelity customer. Does the first Warning mean I cannot do pre-market trading? If that is true, who can?

[image]

**EDIT:**

The order is actually executed when the price target is met. I am confused.

Comment: I would take that 'warning' as informational rather than as a prohibition.  If you do not have approval for pre-market trading then the warning should say something like "Cannot place trade.  You are not approved for pre-market trading".  However, I no longer use Fidelity so take this comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: What time (in ET) did you attempt to place the order?

Comment: I placed the order at about 8:40AM ET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The warning says you *are* placing a pre-market order that *is* eligible for trading until two minutes before the market opens.

They are warning you because pre-market trading carries additional risks, like reduced liquidity and increased volatility, and they want to be sure you are aware of what you are doing.

Comment: But was executed at about 9 am ET

Comment: @peterB Yes. You placed a pre-market trade, and you received a message saying that the order may execute during pre-market hours. The order did, in fact, execute during pre-market hours. What are you confused about?

Comment: Sorry, I read the warning message wrong.